# Duplicate git branch, only files, no history, refs, etc

Tags: git

I'm trying to determine if there is a way in Git to simply take the current status (only files) of a master in repo1 and simply place them in the master of a separate repository repo2. Basically we work on an active repo1 and at the end of the week we want to commit the current code also on a backup repository. I first though this can be achieved through push --mirror but this simply overwrites everything on the second repo and this is not what I'm looking for. I'll shortly describe what I currently do so you can understand what I'm trying to achieve:

1. clone master from repo1(active one) in folder A
2. clone master from repo2(backup one) in folder B
3. delete A/.git folder
4. move B/.git into A. At this point folder A contains the files from repo1 but the .git from repo2.
5. Commit all changes (which git basically sees as some new files, some removed files, etc)

Basically with the above, the entire operation is seen as one simple commit on repo2, without referencing anything from repo1 (I don't need changes from other branches, don't need commit history, etc)
So is there a way to do this in git? Or maybe there is a shell/code snipet out there that achieves this?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive might help too.

Comment: `git commit-tree` lets you create a commit from a set of files. Fetch from active, then `commit-tree` to backup, using backup's `HEAD` as the parent.

Answer (score 0):

you can probably achieve your goal with the help of `git reset`. You add your repo1 as remote repo1 to your repo2, and periodically do at repo2:

```
git fetch repo1 master
git checkout repo1/master
git reset master
git commit -a -m "synced from repo1/master"
```

this way you will get plain snapshots without history between them. You will still have this history in the `repo1/master` remote, if this is undesired you may do this operation at the repo1 repository against a dedicated branch, say `master_backup` and fetch only it to the repo2.